# DS5 Ultimate edition different behavior while accessing first float argument passed to asm call

Tags: arm, neon, ds-5

I am using DS5 ultimate edition for assembly coding and execution on cortex-a53 32 bit.
From my C function i am calling asm function.
The usual norm is when from C function asm function is called and arguments passed, the first float argument is present in s0 register.
For eg., func_asm(float a, float * b);
First float argument 'a' goes to s0 register and argument 'b' is present in r0 register.
But, in my case i am getting the first float argument 'a' in r0 register and 'b' in r1 register.
I am using make file build with below options
--target=arm-arm-none-eabi -march=armv7-a -mcpu=cortex-a53 -mfpu=neon
Please suggest what option needs to be added to get the first float argument correctly in s0 register.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to put the hard/soft float option for the ARM compiler (a Clang fork)

In GCC/Clang, they look like following:

- -mfloat-abi=hard
- -mfloat-abi=softfp
- -mfloat-abi=soft

hard: it's what you are looking for. The compiler will generate machine codes that fully utilize the VFP

softfp: The most commonly used form. Even though the VFP is utilized, the parameter passing occurs via the integer registers

soft: No VFP utilization

Beware that the `hard` option you intend to use isn't that commonly used. And your binaries won't even link to other ones compiled with the `softfp/soft` option.

I strongly advise NOT use the `hard` option unless you know what you are doing.

Comment: Thanks Jake! That was helpful.. I had tried using softfp option. Now i modified to option hard and it takes the float argument from s0 register. As suggested by you using hard option is not advisable so will use softfp and access the arguments accordingly.

Comment: What OS are you running on? Most Linux distros have switched to hardfloat because it's a lot more efficient.